# obtaining the selected option value in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have the following piece of code which resembles a form with a drop-down list. The selected item from the list should be sent to *process.php* page which will do some work.

```
<form name="form" method="GET" action="process.php">
  <div id="extra-components">
    <select name="boolean">
      <option value="and" selected="yes">AND</option>
      <option value="or">OR</option>
      <option value="not">NOT</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

My question is: in the *process.php* file how do I obtain the selected value from the form? via the $_GET method? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question! OP should just try it instead of asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your HTML code you can access `boolean` value by `$_GET['boolean']`. `$_GET['boolean']` will contain one of `<option>`'s `value` element until user will change it in his URL.

Esit:

**Tip**: Don't forget to filter user-submitted data, **always**. HTML, JS restrictions are nothing. 'Always assume that user is malicious' (@MarkB)

Comment: If the user changes it in the url, then the change will be reflected in $_GET. "non-expected changes" is a bogus argument - ALWAYS validate user-submitted data. ALWAYS assume that the user is malicious.

Answer (score 4):

If this is all the code of the form, it probably will not work. What you have forgotten is some submit button or at least some JS code to submit form without the submit button.

The proper code would be something similar to this (notice the additional 'submit' input):

```
<form name="form" method="GET" action="process.php">
  <div id="extra-components">
    <select name="boolean">
      <option value="and" selected="yes">AND</option>
      <option value="or">OR</option>
      <option value="not">NOT</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

And then, after clicking "Submit", the data will be sent to the process.php script and should be accessible by using:

```
$_GET['boolean']
```

Plus, it should be some value from the following strings:

- 'and'
- 'or'
- 'not'

Try it - it should not hurt ;) The example solution:

```
if (isset($_GET['boolean']) && in_array($_GET['boolean'], array('and', 'or', 'not'))) {
    $chosen_boolean = $_GET['boolean'];
} else {
    $chosen_boolean = null;
}
```

Then if the

```
$chosen_boolean === null
```

that means that the value given was inproper or not supported (not from the available options). That should help you avoid any errors regarding the inproper value for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you find the content in `$_GET['boolean']`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The value of the selected option will be passed as the value of the select parameter. So with this code, you'd get

```
$_GET['boolean']
```

set to 'and'